# CSS - DIV whitespace - 'Margin/Padding set to 0px doesn't remove it'

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a one page website. Above the div at the top, I have unwanted whitespace and between each div the same (screenshots below). Margin:0 in the body selector (as recommended from other questions) *does* remove the white space from the left, right, and bottom. Padding:0 in the body selector doesn't seem to do anything. I also tried margin-top: 0px in the div page selectors, but it did nothing. Shows the same in both Chrome and Vivaldi. I'm missing something simple I guess lol.

[image]

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 190px;
}
#nav ul {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Metrophobic", Arial, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
#nav ul a:active {
  color: #3498db;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}
#page1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page3 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page4 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#work">WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page1">
  <a id="home" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Home page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>About page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page3">
  <a id="work" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Work page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page4">
  <a id="contact" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Contact page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also remove the margin from the `<h1>` elements:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 190px;
}
#nav ul {
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul a {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Metrophobic", Arial, serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.5s;
}
#nav ul a:active {
  color: #3498db;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}
#page1 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page3 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
#page4 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#work">WORK</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="page1">
  <a id="home" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Home page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page2">
  <a id="about" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>About page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page3">
  <a id="work" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Work page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
<div id="page4">
  <a id="contact" class="smooth"></a>
  <h1>Contact page content goes here.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm extra slow today... I DID try that earlier, but as an id- #h1 {marginEtc. It's fixed! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)?